# Update to Node version 16 without installing package

Tags: node.js

I am trying to update my node version to 16.

Here what I am doing :

```
--installing nvm
sudo apt install curl 
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash 

-- nvm installer script creates environment entry to login script of the current user.
source ~/.profile  

--node 
nvm install 16
nvm use 16
```

What bothers me, is I need to install a package called nvm.
Is it possible to update node without installing a package ?

Advance Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```